# JavaScript code does not work on mobile when address bar is visible on the page?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

I have a simple piece of javascript code (toggle a class on element) that is not working on mobile (android chrome) when the address bar is visible on the page.

The code is a menu toggle, the + button next to the "Products" menu:

ok right so it doesn't work like this:

[image]

But as soon as I scroll down a little and hide the mobile address bar **IT WORKS!**:

[image]

What is going on? I'm so confused. Why does having the address bar visible change how this code works?

This is the code:

```
m.find( '.menu-dropdown-toggle' ).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $li = $( this ).parents( 'li' ).first();
            if ($li.hasClass( 'toggle-closed' ) || ! ($li.hasClass( 'toggle-open' ) || $li.hasClass( 'current-menu-item' ) || $li.hasClass( 'current_page_ancestor' ) || $li.hasClass( 'current_page_item' ) || $li.hasClass( 'current_page_parent' ))) {
                $li.removeClass( 'toggle-closed' ).addClass( 'toggle-open' );
            } else {
                $li.removeClass( 'toggle-open' ).addClass( 'toggle-closed' );
            }

            return false;
        });
```

Also, this works fine on other mobile websites, it's just this one in particular that is having the address-bar-visible-bug (e.g. http://beautiful.dtbaker.net/ works fine on mobile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is being triggered twice. The first trigger is opening up the menu, the second trigger is closing the menu. This doesn't explain why it is happening when the address bar is visible, but that is what some debugging seems to indicate.

It is possible that another script might be programmatically doing it, but I did not debug that far.

You could use a debounce to ensure the action only gets triggered once in a specific amount of time, which would get around the problem, without actually solving the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove unwanted condition in if block

```
if ($li.hasClass( 'toggle-closed' ) || ! ($li.hasClass( 'toggle-open' ) )   { ....}
```

it will work...